# This code should change the border-radius with React hooks. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: css, button, react-hooks

I'm just starting out with React hooks and I'm trying to make a shape shifting button, when you click on it it changes from square to rounded and back. I want to achieve the effect by changing the border-radius CSS property but it does not seem to work!

I'm puzzled because using similar code I can get the color to change...Please help me!

```
function ShapeChangerButton(){
  const [radius, setRadius] = useState("0px");
    
  function changeShape(){
    if(radius === "0px"){
      setRadius(radius => "30px");
    }
    else{
      setRadius(radius => "0px");
    }    
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button className="standardBtn"
              style={{border-radius: radius}}
              onClick={changeShape}>change shape</button>      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `style={{border-radius: radius}}` ---> `style={{borderRadius: radius}}`

Comment: Oh Wow! great! Could you please explain what the problem is? Should I reformat every CSS property replacing the "-" with camelCase?

Comment: CSS property names in javascript should be in camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style config shoule be :

`style={{ borderRadius: radius }}`

or

```js
function ShapeChangerButton() {
  const [radius, setRadius] = useState("0px");

  function changeShape() {
    if (radius === "0px") {
      setRadius((radius) => "30px");
    } else {
      setRadius((radius) => "0px");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="standardBtn"
        style={{ borderRadius: radius }}
        onClick={changeShape}
      >
        change shape
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```